# Не рисуется линия в Swing

Tags: java, swing, графика

Я пытаюсь сделать графический редактор (что-то типа исполнителя Чертежника из курсов информатики). Хочу нарисовать одну чёрную линию и сетку из линий, но отображается только сетка из линий. Что не так?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.lang.Math;

@SuppressWarnings("ALL")
public class Window extends JFrame {
    private Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    class Canvas extends JPanel {
        ArrayList<Line> lines = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList<Line> grid = new ArrayList();
        class Line {
            private int x1, x2, y1, y2;
            private Color color;
            public Line(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color color) {
                this.x1 = x1;
                this.x2 = x2;
                this.y1 = y1;
                this.y2 = y2;
                this.color = color;
            }
            public void draw(Graphics canvas) {
                canvas.setColor(color);
                canvas.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
                repaint();
            }
        }
        public Canvas() {
            super();
            setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
        public void paintComponent(Graphics canvas) {
            super.paintComponent(canvas);
            canvas.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.clearRect(0, 0, 600, 600);
            for(Line line:grid) {
                line.draw(canvas);
            }
            for(Line line:lines) {
                line.draw(canvas);
            }
        }
        public void addGrid() {
            for (int x = 1; x < 20; x++) {
                grid.add(new Line(x * 30, 0, x * 30, 600, Color.GRAY));
            }
            for (int y = 1; y < 20; y++) {
                grid.add(new Line(0, y * 30, 600, y * 30, Color.GRAY));
            }
        }
        public void addLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2) {
            lines.add(new Line(x1, y1, x2, y2, Color.BLACK));
        }
    }
    Window() {
        // Создаём окно с заголовком
        super();
        setTitle("JPaint");
        setBounds(0, 0, 615, 639);
        canvas.setBounds(0, 0, 600, 600);
        add(canvas);
        setLayout(null);
        // Пытаемся сделать графический интерфейс похожим на интерфейс используемой ОС
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Задаём кнопке закрытия принадлежащее ей действие
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        // Блокируем кнопку "Развернуть на весь экран"
        setResizable(false);
        // Показываем окно
        setVisible(true);
        canvas.addGrid();
        canvas.addLine((int) Math.random() * 600, (int) Math.random() * 600, (int) Math.random() * 600,
            (int) Math.random() * 600);
        canvas.repaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выражение `(int) Math.random() * 600` всегда даст ноль, потому что `Math.random()` возвращает значение меньше единицы. Каст этого значения к инту даёт ноль (отбрасывается всё после точки).

В итоге, Вы рисуете линию начинающуюся в нуле и заканчивающуюся в нуле.

Решения два:

1. Вместо `(int) Math.random() * 600` делать `(int)(Math.random() * 600)`
2. Вместо `(int) Math.random() * 600`

```java
Random random = new Random();
random.nextInt(600);
```

Comment: спасибо) мне хочется щас правда лоб себе фейспалмом пробить из за того что я забыл скобки, но всё равно спасибо)